# Toggle Between Search Icon and Cancel Icon

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I need to toggle between two icons (basically search icon and cancel icon) when a particular element is clicked using jQuery. In the case of the code below, the telegram icon changes to whatsapp icon on click. I want to change back to telegram icon when the whatsapp icon is clicked. I would be grateful if the same code can also be written in JavaScript.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".searchIcon").click(function() {
    $(".search").toggleClass("active");

    $(".searchIcon").attr(
      "src",
      "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQc3j87kFSpq-XNafMC9V14xUyePHRRXpPMed4O_vH_nGWfLjE-dn0&s=0"
    );
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  padding: 0 !important;
  margin: 0 !important;
  font-size: 16px;
  background: black;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  background-color: navy;
}

.preTopNav-Items {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.preTopNav-Items img {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}

.search {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  width: calc(250px + 20px + 7px + 7px);
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: none;
  position: relative;
  height: 28px;
}

.search img:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.searchIcon-wrapper {
  background-color: navy;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  padding: 0 7px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.search input {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  width: 250px;
  padding: 3px 10px;
  font-size: 16px;
  transform: translateX(calc(100% + 34px));
  transition: transform 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.search.active input {
  transform: translateX(-34px);
}

.search.active {
  box-shadow: 10px 4px 10px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  transition: box-shadow 1.5s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>

<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/718022a53c.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="preTopNav-Items search">
    <input type="text" class="searchBar" placeholder="Search..." />
    <div class="searchIcon-wrapper">
      <img class="searchIcon" src="https://www.telegram.org/img/t_logo.png" alt="" style: "width: 20px; height:20px;"/>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a go with this

I extracted the style (you had a typo -colon after style instead of equal sign) and hid the second icon

```
.searchIcon {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}

.searchIcon:nth-child(2) {
  display: none;
}
```

**jQuery**

```js
$(function() {
  $(".searchIcon").on("click",function() {
    $(".search").toggleClass("active");
    $(this).toggle()
    $(this).siblings().toggle()
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  padding: 0 !important;
  margin: 0 !important;
  font-size: 16px;
  background: black;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  background-color: navy;
}

.preTopNav-Items {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.preTopNav-Items img {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}

.search {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  width: calc(250px + 20px + 7px + 7px);
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: none;
  position: relative;
  height: 28px;
}

.search img:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.searchIcon-wrapper {
  background-color: navy;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  padding: 0 7px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.search input {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  width: 250px;
  padding: 3px 10px;
  font-size: 16px;
  transform: translateX(calc(100% + 34px));
  transition: transform 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.search.active input {
  transform: translateX(-34px);
}

.search.active {
  box-shadow: 10px 4px 10px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  transition: box-shadow 1.5s;
}

.searchIcon {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}

.searchIcon:nth-child(2) {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>

<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/718022a53c.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="preTopNav-Items search">
    <input type="text" class="searchBar" placeholder="Search..." />
    <div class="searchIcon-wrapper">
      <img class="searchIcon" src="https://www.telegram.org/img/t_logo.png" />
      <img class="searchIcon whatsapp" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQc3j87kFSpq-XNafMC9V14xUyePHRRXpPMed4O_vH_nGWfLjE-dn0&s=0" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Vanilla JS

I added a new class

```
.searchIcon {
  display: none;
}
.isVisible {
  display:block
}
```

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function() { // page load
  document.querySelector(".searchIcon-wrapper").addEventListener("click", function(e) { // delegation
    const tgt = e.target;
    if (tgt.classList.contains("searchIcon")) { // one of the images
      document.querySelector(".search").classList.toggle("active"); 
      tgt.classList.toggle("isVisible");
      const sib = tgt.classList.contains("whatsapp") ? 1 : 2; // which did we click?
      document.querySelector(".searchIcon:nth-child("+sib+")").classList.toggle("isVisible");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  padding: 0 !important;
  margin: 0 !important;
  font-size: 16px;
  background: black;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  background-color: navy;
}

.preTopNav-Items {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.preTopNav-Items img {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}

.search {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  width: calc(250px + 20px + 7px + 7px);
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: none;
  position: relative;
  height: 28px;
}

.search img:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.searchIcon-wrapper {
  background-color: navy;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  padding: 0 7px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.search input {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  width: 250px;
  padding: 3px 10px;
  font-size: 16px;
  transform: translateX(calc(100% + 34px));
  transition: transform 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.search.active input {
  transform: translateX(-34px);
}

.search.active {
  box-shadow: 10px 4px 10px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  transition: box-shadow 1.5s;
}

.searchIcon {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}

.searchIcon {
  display: none;
}
.isVisible {
  display:block
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>

<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/718022a53c.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="preTopNav-Items search">
    <input type="text" class="searchBar" placeholder="Search..." />
    <div class="searchIcon-wrapper">
      <img class="searchIcon isVisible" src="https://www.telegram.org/img/t_logo.png" />
      <img class="searchIcon whatsapp" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQc3j87kFSpq-XNafMC9V14xUyePHRRXpPMed4O_vH_nGWfLjE-dn0&s=0" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It's working. While the jQuery code seems simple, the pure JavaScript looks intimidating. Also, if you were referring to the following code as containing a typo, I don't think that's the case, else, please point it out. `.preTopNav-Items img {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}`

Comment: The typo was the `:` after style in the image tag - attributes use equals:

Answer (score 1):

I created a reusable function so that you can change another img src like this in the future if you wanted to.

```js
var searchIcon = document.getElementsByClassName("searchIcon")[0];

function togglesrc(obj, icon_off, icon_on){
  if(obj.src == icon_off){
    obj.src = icon_on;
  }
  else{
     obj.src = icon_off;
  }
}

searchIcon.addEventListener("click",function(){
   document.querySelector(".search").classList.toggle("active");
   
   var icon_on = "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQc3j87kFSpq-XNafMC9V14xUyePHRRXpPMed4O_vH_nGWfLjE-dn0&s=0";
   
   var icon_off = "https://www.telegram.org/img/t_logo.png";
  togglesrc(this, icon_off, icon_on);
});
```

```css
body {
  padding: 0 !important;
  margin: 0 !important;
  font-size: 16px;
  background: black;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  background-color: navy;
}

.preTopNav-Items {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.preTopNav-Items img {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}

.search {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  width: calc(250px + 20px + 7px + 7px);
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: none;
  position: relative;
  height: 28px;
}

.search img:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.searchIcon-wrapper {
  background-color: navy;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  padding: 0 7px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.search input {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  width: 250px;
  padding: 3px 10px;
  font-size: 16px;
  transform: translateX(calc(100% + 34px));
  transition: transform 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.search.active input {
  transform: translateX(-34px);
}

.search.active {
  box-shadow: 10px 4px 10px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  transition: box-shadow 1.5s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>

<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/718022a53c.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="preTopNav-Items search">
    <input type="text" class="searchBar" placeholder="Search..." />
    <div class="searchIcon-wrapper">
      <img class="searchIcon" src="https://www.telegram.org/img/t_logo.png" alt="" style: "width: 20px; height:20px;"/>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: OP is using jQuery, why not use it when you have it? Also much more elegant to just toggle between the icons

Comment: @mplungjan, the last sentence of the post says `I would be grateful if the same code can also be written in JavaScript.`  So I took that as vanilla JS, since jQuery is javascript.

Comment: Also `document.getElementsByClassName("search")[0]` can be written better as `document.querySelector(".search")`

Comment: Ok, my answer also has a vanilla version.

Comment: @imvain2 A thousand thanks, but can"t it be any simpler using Vanilla JavaScript?

Answer (score 1):

So what I personally would do is use psuedo elements on the iconWrapper div and then just toggle a class on and off hiding or showing the respective pseudo element. You can either put the images as their content value or use the background-image property and set the images there.

```js
var el = document.querySelector('.iconWrapper');

el.onclick = function() {
  el.classList.toggle('active');
}
```

```css
.iconWrapper {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background: blue;
  position: relative;
}

.iconWrapper:before, .iconWrapper:after {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: -50px;
}

.iconWrapper:before {
 background: green;
 display: none;
}

.iconWrapper:after {
 background: red;
}

.iconWrapper.active:before { display: block; }
.iconWrapper.active:after { display: none; }
```

```html
<div class="iconWrapper"></div>
```

Comment: This is not actually close to what is needed and is not using OPs code

Comment: It is exactly what they asked for "I need to toggle between two icons (basically search icon and cancel icon) when a particular element is clicked using jQuery" It literally does what OP asked along with using vanilla JS(OP Request). Why would it need to use OPs code? It does what OP needs with less code.

Comment: Possibly but if you plug it into the code we can see the difference- I would like to see the slide work

Comment: I can add the slide if OP wants, but this is reusable for OP on anything where they would need to swap an image on click.

Comment: @Bright Jovanny

Here is a fiddle with the search input https://jsfiddle.net/h30q5opa/

Comment: @OMGDrAcula Thank you sir. I'm grateful. The thing is, I am trying to escape the use of pseudo-elements since I don't fully understand the whole concept (at least practically), but this works great.

Comment: @BrightJovanny
I would read up on them as they are pretty commonly used for stuff like this! MDN is a good resource!

Comment: OK. I will do just that.